# How can I access the update object in findOneAndUpdate pre hook?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Consider this

```
const myUpdate = {address: 'abc'};
const update = await myModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 'a0123'}, myUpdate);

myschema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function() {
    const query = this.getQuery(); // {_id: 'a0123'}
    // How can I access and modified `myUpdate` here 
    const myUpdate = this.getUpdate(); // ??
})
```

I'm using mongoose 7.2.2

Comment: what do u get when you log this.getUpdate()

Comment: `this.getUpdate()` is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an issue with Mongoose, `getUpdate` returns the update object in the post hook, but not in the pre-hook, for some reason. You can use `_update`, in the pre-hook like this:

```
const myUpdate = {address: 'abc'};
const update = await myModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 'a0123'}, myUpdate);

myschema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function() {
    const query = this.getQuery(); 
    const myUpdate = this._update;
})
```